# NGINX conditional proxy pass

Tags: nginx, redirect, redirection, proxypass

I hope some guru can give me some help outta here since I don't know anymore where to look or what to do.

I have a single petition from a client that is being a little tricky to me.

My scenario have two machines, one for NGINX and other for Apache. In the Apache machine, they've setup two virtual hosts:

**www.pre.elartedelaamistad.es**

**www.pre.nur-luz.es**

Each website basically loads a infex.html which loads one flash file (which is the site itself) and some jpg files...

Now, some people who have only access to this domain: **prefocus.abg.corp** need/want to see this site in the following way:

**prefocus.abg.corp/elartedelaamistad** -> **www.pre.elartedelaamistad.es**

**prefocus.abg.corp/nur-luz** -> **www.pre.nur-luz.es**

They want to make a proxy_pass, not a redirection.

The Apache machine does not have a virtual host for **prefocus.abg.corp**, that's why if I make a proxy_pass I need to include a **proxy_set_header Host**, but then.., if I make it that way, I may only use one **proxy_set_header Host** in the / location.

I knwow I've explained myself very bad, I just can't found another way to tell it. This petition by itself is weird.

So, ... does anyone has some familiarity with this weird stuff?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get you with the proxy_set_header Host and for the lack of virtual host.
But wouldn't something like do the job ?

```
ProxyPass /elartedelaamistad http://www.pre.elartedelaamistad.es
ProxyPassReverse /elartedelaamistad http://www.pre.elartedelaamistad.es

ProxyPass /nur-luz http://www.pre.nur-luz.es
ProxyPassReverse /nur-luz http://www.pre.nur-luz.es
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, I already managed to solve this out, but not with this original scenario which is quite messy in my opinion. Y setup two diferent virtual hosts in nginx and each one makes a proxy pass to the corresponding apache virtual host.
Thanks again mate!